# Darryldecode Cart Update Error Return preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Darryldecode Laravel Shopping Cart on my Laravel 5.0

Link : https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

When i apply the function Cart::update :

```
$id = Input::get('id');
$qty = Input::get('qty-n');
Cart::update($id, array(
'quantity' => array(
'relative' => false,
'value' => $qty
),
));
```

It's return me an error :

> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given .

How exactly to use this function?

Thank you

Comment: Show some research effort... what have you found when searching for a solution?

Comment: no result in google accept my own question and others for php not laravel .